# To Get Duplicate as well as original items from an array in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nscountedset

I have an array, as

(John, Jane, John)

I want to get duplicates,as well as original elements of array like

(John,John)
I am able to get single occurance from code
here

```
NSArray *names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"John", @"Jane", @"John", nil];
NSCountedSet *set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:names];

for (id item in set)
{
    NSLog(@"Name=%@, Count=%lu", item, (unsigned long)[set countForObject:item]);
    if((unsigned long)[set countForObject:item]>1){
        NSLog(@"of repeated element-----=%@",item);
    }
}
```

"Name of repeated element-----John" but i want all occurences of repeated element like "Name of repeated element-----John,John" .

Comment: From Wikipedia in Set (Mathematics)

A set is a collection of well defined and distinct objects.
Perhaps the confusion derives from the fact that a set does not depend on the way its elements are displayed. A set remains the same if its elements are allegedly repeated or rearranged.

As such, the programming languages I know would not put an element into a set if the element already belongs to it, or they would replace it if it already exists, but would never allow a duplication.

Comment: So you want to separate duplicate elements into another array?

Comment: Yes i want to seperate duplicate elements with its original its repeated value like for array [John, Jane, John] i want to seperate new array as [John,John]

Comment: At present i am able to seperate single occurrence of repeated element like for[John, Jane, John] i am able to get [John] from mention code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **Using NSPredicate**:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"John", @"Jane", @"John",@"Jane",@"Jane", nil];
NSMutableArray *arrResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSCountedSet *set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array];
for(id name in set)
   {
        if([set countForObject:name] > 1 ){
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF = %@", name];
            [arrResult addObjectsFromArray:[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
        }
    }
    //
    NSLog(@"%@",arrResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your final purpose, the result you want looks meaningless. Anyway, for study purpose, following is an implementation ;)

```
NSArray *names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"John", @"Jane", @"John", nil];

NSMutableDictionary *countDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSString *name in names) {
    if (countDict[name] == nil) {
        countDict[name] = [NSMutableString stringWithString:name];
    }
    else{
        NSMutableString *repeatedName = (NSMutableString *)countDict[name];
        [repeatedName appendString:@","];
        [repeatedName appendString:name];
    }
}
[countDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *_Nonnull name, NSString * _Nonnull repeatedNames, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    if (repeatedNames.length > name.length) {
        NSLog(@"Name of repeated element-----%@",repeatedNames);
    }
}];
```

Output: Name of repeated element-----John,John

Comment: my final purpose is to let user know that there are duplicate entries in tableview which i am populating and then let user delete any one of Duplicate element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code Using `loop`

```
NSArray *names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"John", @"Jane", @"John",@"John", nil];
        NSCountedSet *set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:names];
        NSMutableArray *repeatedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (id item in set)
        {
            NSLog(@"Name=%@, Count=%lu", item, (unsigned long)[set countForObject:item]);
            if((unsigned long)[set countForObject:item]>1){
                NSLog(@"of repeated element-----=%@",item);
                for(int i=0;i<[set countForObject:item];i++)
                 {
                    [repeatedArray addObject:item];
                 }

        }
```

Output : john,john,john